# How can I configure a Spring Boot app to use two message properties files?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, internationalization, message

I have a Spring Boot app that pulls messages from `messages.properties` and its language-specific partners (e.g. `messages_fr.properties` for French users).  I'd like to add a second set of messages files, for messages that are shared across several of my organization's applications.  Let's call it `commonmessages.properties` (and `commonmessages_fr.properties` etc.).

How can I tell Spring Boot to use *both* files for messages?

Comment: Good find, thanks. I did a significant amount of searching but unfortunately the text "as shown in the following example" is not likely to get indexed by a search engine as having anything to do with this question or topic, so I think it's still a good question to have here on SO.

Comment: How is the documentation, which has a link to `internationalization` not clear? That is exactly where you need to be.

Comment: When it comes to Spring, that's not "the" documentation.  There is a whole library of official docs, not even including mkyoung, Baeldung, etc.  And searchability matters. They don't use keywords.  It's just something they do in a code snippet and barely mention.

Comment: The only official documentation is the documentation from the source, hence Spring.io. The others are tutorials and explainations, for which some or good, some or worse and some are plain wrong or out-dated.

Comment: @ROHAN. It does exactly solve/help this problem. It's the official documentation and shows **exactly** how to provide multiple resources and it clearly states in a note that you just need to `,` seperate the resources. So it is answering this question twice.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As seen in an example in [this Spring Boot "features" overview](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/spring-boot-features.html#boot-features-internationalization), you can set the property `spring.messages.basename` in `application.properties` or `application.yml` to a comma-separated string.

In this case:

`spring.messages.basename=messages,commonmessages`

EDIT: I did a bit of testing and it *seems like* the entry listed first has precedence, i.e., if messages of the same name are found in both files, the app will use the one from `messages` and not the one from `commonmessages`.